# Associate if exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have two tables: `users` and `user_location_data`. I need to get all records within `users`, and associate it with the matching data within `user_location_data` if it exists - but still get the user data if it doesn't. Example output:

```
User ID | Name     | Location Data
--------|----------|--------------------------
      2 | John     | 
      3 | Jane     | Lorem Ipsum 
      6 | Harry    | 
      9 | Lloyd    | Lorem Ipsum
     22 | Patricia | Lorem Ipsum
```

This can easily be accomplished with a simple loop and multiple queries, but that seems a little neanderthal to me. A regular relational query (eg `SELECT * FROM users u, user_location_data uld WHERE u.user_id = uld.user_id`) will only fetch the users that have a matching location data record. Is there any way I can do this with a single query?

Comment: Good to know! I'll make sure to follow from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN user_location_data uld ON u.user_id = uld.user_id
```

Comment: Wish I could +2 this - once for the correct answer, and once for the awesome article. This answers so many questions I've had. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeMoose That article helped me a million back in the day too. Jeff Atwood is the initial creator of Stack Overflow. You should go back and read a lot of his blog  :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html